# Why does my icon handling code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt, nullpointerexception

I have added an image for my button,but when I run that frame this exception will be thrown .why?please help me.

```
init:

deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:138)
        at ClientGUI.IdAndPasswordFrame.initComponents(IdAndPasswordFrame.java:91)
        at ClientGUI.IdAndPasswordFrame.<init>(IdAndPasswordFrame.java:22)
        at ClientGUI.IdAndPasswordFrame$4.run(IdAndPasswordFrame.java:200)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

line 138:

```
public ImageIcon (URL location) {
    this(location, location.toExternalForm());
}
```

line91:

```
 jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif"))); // NOI18N
```

**I use this poor checking (Peter Lang recommended)which is:System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif")); and it returns null,why? please help me.**

Comment: Is "jButton1" set to something?

Comment: yes ,I set an image for this button which name is yahoo_1.gif

Comment: I use this poor checking (Peter Lang recommended)which is:System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif"));
and it returns null,why? please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means, that `getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif")` returns `null`.

[JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) states that this happens if

> the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.

1. Check if `getResource` really returns `null`:
   `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif"));`
2. Make sure that your path is correct and that it is in your classpath.

**EDIT**:

I just tried it with NetBeans. I created the following structure

```
Source Packages
  Images
    yahoo_1.gif
```

and your code worked fine. Is this your structure?

Try to right-click on your application and select `Clean and Build`.

Comment: I do the first step which is:Check if getResource really returns null:
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif"));and it returns null,what should i do? please help me

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Thanks for editing, i used Oracle's `NULL` instead of Java's `null` :)

Comment: Thanks a million I have used Clean and Build ,and the code worked fine,thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In order to fix this, the images need to be copied in the **bin** directory - not in **src** directory.

Otherwise you will get null all the time on **getClass().getResource("image.png")**. 
The path is **not null** and you can set it as the above - only if you copy the images that you need inside the binary directory, where .class files for your project are located.

This fixed the problem. Let me know if I helped in this.

Ioana

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was:

1. Look into the jar file or in the bin folder(the one with .class files) and see the path of image.
2. List item

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif")` returns `null` i.e. the .gif cannot be found on your classpath. (Images versus images maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

The URL being passed in is null from this line:

```
getClass().getResource("/Images/yahoo_1.gif")
```

From the JDK documentation:

> [getResource(..) returns] A URL object for reading the resource,
>   or null if the resource could not be
>   found or the invoker doesn't have
>   adequate privileges to get the
>   resource

Maybe you meant ("Images/yahoo_1.gif") - i.e. relative path not absolute?

Comment: I use netbeans ,and I choose just icon menu for adding a photo.

Answer (score -1):

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionperformed(ActionEvent event){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand()));
        }

}
```

Comment: this is unrelated to the question

Answer (score -2):

After reviewing some things when trying to add an image I was presented with the same problem that usually occurs in project with maven.

I found a solution that uses the full path to be able to access the image. Also, create a function that returns an icon with the image and automatically scaled according to the dimensions that are sent to it.

Path -> directory where the image is located, width -> width of the icon, heigth-> height of the icon I hope it serves you, this is my first contribution in the community

```java
public Icon getIcon(String ruta, int width, int heigth) {
        Image image = (new ImageIcon(ruta)).getImage().getScaledInstance(width, heigth, 0);
        Icon mIcono = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(image);
        return mIcono;
    }
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).