# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I'm a newbie in Java and I'm trying to add a button in my window, but I'm having some troubles.

First of all, I created a new jLabel, left blank the "text" and chose a image from my images folder (inside my project). After that, I added a new jButton, and again leftblank the "text" and chose a imagem from my images folder.

#### Here's my project structure:

```
control
Images
|- A lot of images (fireworks png)

Model
|- Connection.java

View
|- MainMenu.java
```

I think it's everything ok, but when I try to run this code, I have the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at view.TelaInicialLocus.initComponents(MainMenu.java:53)
    at view.TelaInicialLocus.<init>(MainMenu.java:17)
    at view.TelaInicialLocus$2.run(MainMenu.java:133)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

#### Lines of code:

```
line 17:
initComponents();

line 53/57:
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/logo2.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200));
        jLabel3.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200));

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/entrar.fw.png")));

line 115/145:
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaInicialLocus.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaInicialLocus.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaInicialLocus.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaInicialLocus.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaInicialLocus().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am willing to help with more information and code. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the line at `MainMenu.java:53` ?

Comment: What is your code which you are writing.? Post some bundle of codes...

Comment: And post them with poper line numbers if possible

Comment: Line 53:  jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/logo2.png"))); // NOI18N

Comment: `getClass().getResource("/images/logo2.png"))` is returning `null` . Just check it .

Comment: I solved my problem with the question above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019914/why-does-my-icon-handling-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception

Comment: use getClass().getResource("images/logo2.png") ...just remove that extra '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a good answer in this question: [Why does my icon handling code throw a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019914/why-does-my-icon-handling-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception)

#### I just right-click on my project and select "Clean and Build".

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before....

use getClass().getResource("images/logo2.png") ...just remove that extra '/'

That extra slash is causing the problem...